# How can i disable an input text box based on dropdown selection value using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have the following in JavaScript for AngularJS

```
$("#listOptionFruit").kendoDropDownList({
    autoBind: true,
    filter: 'contains',
    dataSource: $scope.listOptionFruitList,
    select: $scope.listOptionFruitSelect
});

$scope.listOptionFruitSelect = function (e)
{            
   $scope.listOptionFruit = e.dataItem;
   if ($scope.listOptionFruit === 'Strawberry') {
       $scope.enableMe = true;
   } 
   else 
   {
       $scope.enableMe =  false;
   }                               
}
```

and the cshtml side is as follows:

```
<label for="listOptionFruit">Fruits</label>
<input id="listOptionFruit" name="listOptionFruit"  required />


<label for="myValue">MyValue</label>
<input type="text"  id="myValue" ng-disabled="enableMe"  />
```

So the value is correct for enableMe , but the text box doesn't seem to be disabled or the action doesn't seem to take effect.

So if the user selects Strawberry from the list then the text box is disabled , else it is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the event happens outside the AngularJS framework, it needs to be bound with `$apply`:

```
$("#listOptionFruit").kendoDropDownList({
    autoBind: true,
    filter: 'contains',
    dataSource: $scope.listOptionFruitList,
    select: function (ev) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.listOptionFruitSelect(ev);
        });
    }
});
```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

[image]

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)

Comment: sorted  with above solution by georgeawg. I used a wrong variable.